# Can I use "tag = value" in the ... of lapply?

Tags: r

Let's say I have a list of vectors, and I want to convert it to a list of one-column data.frames, like so:

```
ex <- list(1:3, 4:6, 5:9)
ex1 <- lapply(ex, function(i) data.frame(col1 = i))
```

Is it possible to do this without the anonymous function?  That is, it would be nice to do something like this:

```
ex2 <- lapply(ex, data.frame, `col1 = i`)
```

Comment: `lapply(lapply(ex, data.frame), setNames, "col1")`

Comment: What you are trying to do with `tag = value` is regarding making extra columns, not naming the columns that are already there. The way to make names for several objects is with the `setNames` function. Alternatively, note that `as.data.frame` takes `col.names` argument, but it has trouble with the unnamed list. `matrix` takes explicit dimnames, and so converting with `as.data.frame.matrix` is trivial after `ex %>% lapply(matrix, dimnames = list(NULL,"col1"))`

Comment: @Frank edited, thanks.  @Richard, thank you, that's a good workaround.  An alternative would be `setNames(as.data.frame(ex), "col1")`.  @shayaa thanks, I'll look into the `col.names` argument.  I actually wanted to see if this type of argument can be passed to via the `...` in `lapply` in general (not just for naming or creating columns in `data.frame`).  For example, it would be nice to be able to pass arguments to `switch` in a similar way.

Comment: @shayaa Where is this `col.names` arg? `?as.data.frame` does not show it.

Comment: @Frank The `col.names` argument is under the `as.data.frame` method for "list".

Comment: Ok -- seems it's some new feature since R 3.3.0 https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/NEWS.html